# Creating a living copy of a shared exchange calendar

Tags: 2007, calendar, outlook, sync, exchange

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

I am building a platform for my team to view all of our calendar events through SharePoint.
Our calendar is setup through the manager's personal calendar , and we all copy our personal appointments to it, giving us a nice display of all of the events happening in our group each day.(tech savvy decisions are rare here, a new calendar should have just been created.)
Since it is not my calendar, I can't just create a 2-way sync between it and SharePoint.
And because it is the personal calendar of another employee, I cant just copy events or set up any automatic sync's with it.

My plan of action is to create an exchange calendar clone (owned by me) that is sync'd to SharePoint. 
I was trying to use this [macro set](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/copy-new-appointments-to-another-calendar-using-vba/) to catch and copy all new events created on the manager's calendar, to my separate calendar, which would then sync up to the SharePoint calendar.

Unfortunately my VBA skill is a solid 1/10, and these macros are just creating an infinite amount of appointments and not copying anything.

Any solutions to this problem?